# Spinel or salt?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, crystal-structure, materials

In reaction of $\ce{Al2O3}$ with $\ce{NaOH}$, we get product written as "$\ce{NaAlO2}$", "$\ce{Na2Al2O4}$" or just "$\ce{Na2O.Al2O3}$".

My question is what's the ***real*** structure of this compound? Spinel or a salt of aluminate anion ($\ce{AlO2-}$)? Maybe just mixture?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60452/reaction-between-alumina-and-aqueous-sodium-hydroxide-which-ones-right/60463#60463

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia article of sodium aluminate:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_aluminate)

> Anhydrous sodium aluminate, $\ce{NaAlO2}$, contains a
>   three-dimensional framework of corner linked $\ce{AlO4}$ tetrahedra.
>   The hydrated form $\ce{NaAlO2·5/4H2O}$ has layers of $\ce{AlO4}$
>   tetrahedra joined into rings and the layers are held together by
>   sodium ions and water molecules that hydrogen bond to O atoms in the
>   $\ce{AlO4}$ tetrahedra.

The composition of sodium aluminate is basically written as $\ce{NaAlO2, NaAl(OH)4}$ (hydrated), $\ce{Na2O·Al2O3}$ or $\ce{Na2Al2O4}$.